# Matlab array test file improve

Tags: arrays, matlab, text-files

I'm stuck and frustrated :P My problem is I'm trying to get numbers before letters like exemple:

```
159753 gum, gabriel
```

test.txt is:

```
gum, gabriel 159753
```

But so far my code looks like this:

```
clc 
fid = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
R = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
R{1}
fclose(fid);
```

I have also tried:

```
clc                     
fid = fopen('test.txt', 'r');    
R = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s');
All =[R{3},R{1},R{2}];
Disp(All)
fclose(fid);
```

and I do get my numbers before letters but it looks so bloody weird so i don't know how to improve this code?

I just hope I have explained everything because I suck at arrays .

Comment: What is "it looks so bloody weird" supposed to mean? That was a decent answer. If you want something else, you really should improve the question first.

Comment: If you're just looking to "format" your output, try: `All =[R{3},', ',R{1},' ',R{2}];` instead of simply `All =[R{3},R{1},R{2}];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access one more level of cells so that you won't see the curly brackets when you display the results. I also added some spaces between the strings.

```
fid = fopen('test.txt', 'r');    
R = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s');
All =[R{3}{1}, ' ', R{1}{1}, ' ', R{2}{1}];
disp(All)
fclose(fid);
```